# "Belief p" vs. "belief that p"

Tags: that

There is a difference between

> A believes P.    >>> Alan **believes** what you say.

and

> A believes that p. >>> Alan **believes that** she will come
>   back.

It is thus common in philosophical texts to say "one's **belief** **that** P" when P is a whole proposition.

Now which of the the followings are correct?

Alan forms **the belief that** P.

or

Alan forms **the belief P**.

The "belief that p" seems to be way more common. [Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20belief%20that%20p%2Cthe%20belief%20p&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20belief%20that%20p%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20belief%20p%3B%2Cc0) But it sounds a bit awkward, doesn't it?

Comment: In English, 'that' can often be dropped (as intro to a relative clause) with no change in semantics.

Answer (score 1):

When what follows is a clause, the *that* can usually be dropped.

When it is not a clause, the optional deletion is not possible: the presence or absence of *that* may alter the meaning and in some cases the grammaticality.

In your specific case, *the belief P* is not grammatical except with the interpretation that P is in apposition to the NP *the belief*: i.e. P is a sort of name or designator for the belief. For the meaning you want, it must be *the belief that P*. (*The belief in P* is also possible, but in most cases has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"That" is being used as a subordinating conjunction.  As such, it requires the two parts of the sentence it connects to be compete on their own.

Consider the fragment "Alan believes **that** what you say".  We need to make the second part complete "Alan believes that what you say **is false**".

We can remove "that", and things are okay: "Alan believes what you say is false".  However, the sentence becomes less readable, because "Alan believes what you say..." is already a complete sentence.  By adding "that", we ensure the reader will go into the rest of the sentence knowing it will be a complete concept.